# SoundCloud API - Get my tracks by Release Number

Tags: api, filtering, soundcloud

Can I query my tracks and get right to the one with a particular release number?

Or do I have to get all my tracks then filter through them with something like `for each`

I know how to do the latter but it takes some time. If the former, what GET string would I use? I tried something like this but it's not working.

`http://api.soundcloud.com/users/12345?release=1071&client_id=myClientID`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, it looks like GETting by release number is not supported.  Most GETs are very broad and must be filtered.

Comment: How about through PHP? Is there any solution?